# Dividing an integer into a fixed number of integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the formula for dividing an integer into a fixed number of integers where the greatest distance between consecutive integers is 1.

Dividing 10 into 4 integers we can get:

```
[3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Dividing 7 into 4 integers we can get:

```
[2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Dividing 10 into 8 integers we can get:

```
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Do you want the number of ways to it, or just one way. Have you any idea yourself?

Comment: I just need one way to do it. I tried coming up with a formula but the only reliable part seemed to be deriving the largest integer in the sequence which i got from the ceiling of `N / n` where `N` is being divided into `n` pieces. Wasn't sure how to calculate when to decrement the next number in the sequence. To be honest I don't know the best way to derive such a formula so if you have any pointers re a general approach to figuring out a problem like this that would also be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split $N$ into $n$ pieces, the small pieces are of size $\lfloor \frac Nn \rfloor$ and the large ones are one larger.  There are $N \pmod n$ (sometimes written $N\%n$ in computerese) of the larger ones.

Comment: How do you know what the large piece is given just `N` and `n`? Is it the ceiling of `N / n`?

Comment: +1 But BIOS is correct, a slightly more accurate statement of the size of the large ones would be $\lceil\frac{N}{n}\rceil$ because the pieces might all be one size.

Comment: Hi @almagest thanks for that. How did you go about deriving the formula or do you know it from some prior application?

Comment: @BIOS If I met it before it was long ago! But the idea is obvious once you see it, it is just a question of how to express the size properly.

Comment: @BIOS:  it depends what you want to do when you can divide $N$ by $n$ exactly.  As I write it, the larger pieces are one larger, but there are none of them.  As you write it, the two sizes are the same because the ceiling and floor are equal.  Both ways make sense, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Allowing fractions, you would split exactly as

$$\left[\frac{10}4,\frac{10}4,\frac{10}4,\frac{10}4\right].$$

Adding those fractions from left to right, you get

$$\left[\frac{10}4,\frac{20}4,\frac{30}4,\frac{40}4\right].$$

Then taking the integer parts,

$$[2,5,7,10].$$

And finally the pairwise differences

$$[2,3,2,3].$$

Other examples,

$$\left[\frac74, \frac74,\frac74,\frac74\right]\to\left[\frac74, \frac{14}4,\frac{21}4,\frac{28}4\right]\\
\to[1,3,5,7]\to[1,2,2,2].$$

$$\left[\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8,\frac{10}8\right]\to\left[\frac{10}8,\frac{20}8,\frac{30}8,\frac{40}8,\frac{50}8,\frac{60}8,\frac{70}8,\frac{80}8\right]\\
\to[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10]\to[1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2].$$

This doesn't just give you the numbers, but a permutation that minimizes the cumulated error.

Algebraically, the numbers are

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n(i+1)}m\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{ni}m\right\rfloor.$$

They are in close relation with the [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) that draws on oblique line on a square grid.

---

Note that by the definition of integer division,

$$m=qn+r=q(n-r)+(q+1)r$$ where $q=\lfloor n/m\rfloor$ is the integer quotient and $r=m\bmod n$ the remainder, such that $0\le r<n$. So among the $n$ numbers, $n-r$ of them equal $q$ and $r$ equal $q+1$.

Comment: edit to $[2,5,7,10]$

Comment: @GCab: done, thks.